# convert unicode to UTF8 string

Tags: python, selenium

I need to convert what I think is a unicode string from selenium to a readable UTF8 string (there is a `u` in the beginning of the string)

But what if the string already is UTF8 encoded? Then the multibyte chars will be double encoded

```
td.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem? unicode-strings are supposed to be encoding-agnostic, and encoding would give you a byte-string (basically just a sequence of bytes)

Comment: There is no such thing as an "UTF-8 encoded string" in Python. A string is series of Unicode characters. UTF-8 is a series of `byte` values.

Answer (score 0):

If the text in unicode, you could perform a encode operation to convert into utf-8. If it's already in utf-8, it won't be double encoded. It'll just throw an error stating :

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode